# Is it possible to trigger an event when a field is valid (html5)?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In html5 fields can be valid. (for example an `type="email"` has to follow the email convention etc).

Using css you can select valid fields with the psuedo-element:
`input:valid`.

Is it possible to trigger an event when the input becomes valid?

Comment: There are events fired during the validation process, but not while stuff is being just typed into the form. *edit* - actually you only get "invalid" events for elements that are not valid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `checkValidity()` method on the input's DOM element you want to check.

```
function isValidInput (input) {
    return $(input)[0].checkValidity();
}
```

Then you can run that function on whatever event, like `blur` or `keyup` or a button.

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/nSLQb/1/